# PHP round number up or down inside number_format()

Tags: php

I have something like this:

```
$exp = 1555678;
```

if i put $exp inside number_format() the out come will be like:

```
   echo number_format($exp);//1,555,678
```

and if i put them inside round() function will be like:

```
   echo round(number_format($exp));//1
```

but i need something like 1,556,000

> whatever the exp is, it's should round() only 3 number behind first comma
>
> Or there is another way to work with this case?

Comment: divide by 1000, round, multiply by 1000

Comment: Number format returns a string. What is the data type input of round(). Hint: not string

Comment: @Andreas it's float..

Comment: Please search SO before posting a question.

Comment: @mickmackusa I’m really grateful for your help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both approaches

```
$exp = 1555678;
echo number_format(round($exp, -3));
```

which gives: 1,556,000

Comment: This question is a duplicate.

Comment: @mickmackusa my bad, it wasn't when I answered :)

Comment: (It was a duplicate since March 1 of 2011)

Comment: OK mate, I've gotta get back to work

Comment: Thank you for taking the trouble to answer my questions :D

Comment: @Murphy'zlaw No problem